# GRASS Gis v 6.4.4. KeyError: 'version' when start

Tags: python, grass-gis

When I try to start the GRASS it gives me the following error

```
GRASS 6.4.4 (Hellas):~ > ERROR: MAPSET Hellas - permission denied
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/grass64/etc/wxpython/wxgui.py", line 140, in <module>
  sys.exit(main())
File "/opt/grass64/etc/wxpython/wxgui.py", line 133, in main
  app = GMApp(workspaceFile)
File "/opt/grass64/etc/wxpython/wxgui.py", line 45, in __init__
  wx.App.__init__(self, False)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/wx-3.0-gtk2/wx/_core.py", line 8628, in __init__
 self._BootstrapApp()
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/wx-3.0-gtk2/wx/_core.py", line 8196, in _BootstrapApp
 return _core_.PyApp__BootstrapApp(*args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/grass64/etc/wxpython/wxgui.py", line 79, in OnInit
 workspace = self.workspaceFile)
File "/opt/grass64/etc/wxpython/lmgr/frame.py", line 83, in __init__
 self.baseTitle = _("GRASS GIS %s Layer Manager") % grass.version()['version']
KeyError: 'version'
```

My operating system is Manjaro linux.

What cause this problem and how can this fixed?

Comment: Please check if the ownership of the MAPSET directory  "Hellas" is yours (it is within the location you use). Perhaps you are working on a network drive? Extra note for wx-3.0: a series of wxPython3 fixes have been made in GRASS GIS 7.0.0: http://grass.osgeo.org/news/42/15/GRASS-GIS-7-0-0/

Comment: No I don't work on a network, but I work on a second drive on my machine. I use an ssd for my primary disk and I have a second drive where I store all of my data.

Comment: Perhaps it is really a wxPython3 issue since GRASS GIS 6 is not really ready for that. You may install GRASS GIS 7.0.0 in parallel. In case of still having wxPython3 issues in G7 I am sure that they would get fixed quickly.

Comment: I install GRASS 7 but the problem isn't fixed.

Comment: OK, so some more work might be needed. Can you please report it here? http://trac.osgeo.org/grass/ Then the developers may pick it up. Thanks

Comment: Ok I will report. But I forgot to mention that the location that I store my data is a second drive attached on my system. I have a primary ssd disk for my operation system and a second drive for my data. Is it possible that this is causing the problem?

Comment: Thanks for reporting - you already got an answer there :)

Answer (score 1):

For the record:

The reporter opened a ticket http://trac.osgeo.org/grass/ticket/2610 - the answer is that the problem has already been solved in GRASS GIS 6.4.svn. It will be published with the upcoming 6.4.5 release or a nightly/weekly snapshot is used.